# What is the minimum guaranteed time for a process in windows?

Tags: c, windows, performance, real-time, scheduler

I have a process that feeds a piece of hardware (data transmission device) with a specific buffer size. What can I reasonable expect from the windows scheduler windows to ensure I do not get a buffer underflow?

My buffer is 32K in size and gets consumed at ~800k bytes per second.

If I fill it in 16k byte batches that is one batch every 20ms. However, what is my lower limit for filling it. If say, I call sleep(0) in my filling loop what is my reasonable worst case scheduling interval?

OS = Windows XP SP3
Dual Core 2.2Ghz

Note, I am making an API call to check the buffer fill level and a call to the driver API to pass it the data. I am assuming these are scheduling points that Windows could make use of in addition to the sleep(0).

I would like to (as a process) play nice and still meet my realtime deadline. The machine is dedicated to this task but needs to receive the data over the network and send it to the IO device.

What can I expect for scheduler perfomance?
What else do I need to take into account.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guaranteed worst-case.  Losing the CPU for hundreds of milliseconds is quite possible.  You are subject to whatever kernel threads are doing, they'll always run with a higher priority than you can ever get.  Running into a misbehaving NIC, USB or audio driver is a problem you'll constantly be fighting.  Unless you can control the hardware.

If you can survive occasional under-runs then make sure that the I/O request you use to get the device data is a waitable event.  Windows likes scheduling threads that are blocking on an I/O request that completed ahead of all other ones.  Polling with a Sleep() is not a good strategy.  It burns CPU cycles needlessly and the scheduler won't favor the thread at all.

If you can't survive the under-runs then you need to consider a device driver.

Comment: I guess you mean interrupt-level and DPC-level threads; there are other, lower-priority threads in the kernel.

Comment: Sleep might not be bad: at worst it might hog waste CPU, which isn't bad on a dedicated machine (hogging the CPU is possibly what he wants to do). The reason for Sleep might be that he's trying to keep the transmit buffer as full as possible.

Comment: Yes, a device driver. A standard serial port, for example, has a 1-byte or 16-byte hardware transmit buffer; the serial port driver accepts multiple unlimited-length buffers from the application: so a good application strategy is to do WriteFile on 2 large buffers, and use I/O request to be woken when the driver has used/exhausted/returned one of them: the application can then send down the next (3rd) buffer, while the devce driver still already has a (the 2nd) buffer.

Comment: sleep() calls yield() eventually, other processes and threads can run while "sleeping." Not sure about the hogging thing. :-)

Comment: Is there a reason an event-based scheme would not work? When the buffer is full or almost full, trigger an event?

Comment: @JustBoo He's worried about under-runs, not over-runs: the transmit buffer will be full when he writes to it, and he wants to keep it as full as possible (so he wants to write to it continually, almost continously).

Comment: Even worse than kernel level threads - BIOS SMI handlers can take over the CPU for hundreds of milliseconds at a time too.

Answer (score 3):

> What is the minimum guaranteed time for a process in windows?

There is no guarantee: Windows is not a real-time O/S.

> What else do I need to take into account

- What else is running on the machine (something high priority might preempt you)
- How much RAM you have (system performance changes a lot when RAM is in short supply)
- Whether you're dong I/O (because you might e.g. stall while waiting for disk or network access)

> I would like to (as a process) play nice and still meet my realtime deadline. The machine is dedicated to this task but needs to receive the data over the network and send it to the IO device.

Consider setting the priority of your process and/or thread at "real time priority".